# having trouble asssigning existing code to a GUI in Powershell 2016

Tags: powershell, user-interface, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I want to assign a GUI to the existing code in PowerShell 2016. The script is `Import-Module Active Directory`. Its when I need to edit a users credential in the active directory through the GUI.

How do I connect the existing code to the GUI's buttons to retrieve the information needed from Active Directory.

Comment: probably easier using AD snapin in this case, but googling powershell gui will help you, check this https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/

Comment: @4c74356b41 thnks for the response. I am a novice dev. Do you mind explaining it to me in a different way on how to implement it in PowerShell Studio ?